# LocalStorage.getItem('token) returns null

Tags: angular, typescript

In my code, I need to set the header authorization (Bearer + token), but when I print it, the bearer is null but there is a variable token exist in my localstorage

code auth.services.ts

```js
getToken() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    console.log(token);
    return token;
  }
```

token-interceptor.ts

```js
constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

intercept(req, next) {

  const tokenizeReq = req.clone({
    setHeaders: {
      authorization: `Bearer ${this.authService.getToken()}`
    }
  });
  return next.handle(tokenizeReq);
}
```

**Outputs in console**

[image: Outputs in console]

**Network variables**

[image: Network variables]

**LocalStorage**
[image: LocalStorage]

I don't know how to set null. Why is this happening

Comment: could you please share the above code and reproduce the error in a stackblitz link ?

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes any difference, but 'Authorization' has an 'A' in uppercase. And, why you don't just return the token directly from localstorage? Like this: 
`getToken() {
   return localStorage.getItem('token');
 }`
 Hope it helps!

Comment: Where is the code that sets the token initially?

Comment: Really i dont set initially token in any constructor

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Usj6O69.png here set token value

Answer (score 0):

i think it get some time to set token as a local variable pls use await and async function to generate and set token

eg:-

```
async setToken(token){
  await localStorage.setItem('token', token);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
}, 50);
```

if you are trying to fetch the token value just after setting it, it will not works and you will get null, try to call `localStorage.getItem` after the call `setItem` be finished.

Comment: returns undefined